# ASIHTTP request returning NULL response in ios 6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, asihttprequest

I am developing an app in ios which is ARC enabled. Inside this, I have a functionality of image uploading into the server using the .net web services.  The web services send a json string which containing status of the request i.e., success/failure. And I am using ASI HTTP request for hitting the services and sbjson for parsing the response.

My case,  if i am running this image uploading functionality in ios6 device, the response which I am receiving from the .net web services is showing as null randomly[once in 10 or 15 times]. But, in server side log files shows that it is succeeded like that and the image uploading is also done in the server.

But, this functionality is working fine in ios5.

Can any one help us?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: use AFNetworking instead of ASIHTTP as its deprecated??